# Is it possible to pass a connection string to StrictRedis in python?

Tags: python-3.x, redis

I am unable to find an answer to this while googling, but it seems like it should be something that is doable. I am retrieving a Redis connection string from my password manager. I would like to take this connection string and pass it to Redis. All the examples I have seen are in the following format.

```
redis.StrictRedis(host=myHostname, port=6380, password=myPassword, ssl=True)
```

I have also tried doing the following.

```
r = redis.StrictRedis()
r.ConnectionString = myConnectionString
```

That results in an error

> ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Is there a way to simply pass this connection string? Seems counterproductive for me to have to retrieve it and then split it up.

My connection string looks like this after it has been retrieved.

```
xxx.redis.cache.yyy.net:6380,password=redacted,ssl=True,abortConnect=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a connection string that the Python Redis client supports; that's a [.NET StackExchange.Redis configuration string](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html). You'll have to parse out the components yourself, skipping the `abortConnection` option:

```
hostport, *options = myConnectionString.split(",")
host, _, port = hostport.partition(":")
arguments = {}
for option in options:
    opt, _, value = option.partition("=")
    if opt == "port":
        value = int(value)
    elif opt == "ssl":
        value = value.lower() == "true"
    elif opt == "abortConnect":
        continue
    arguments[opt] = value

client = redis.Redis(host, port=int(port), **arguments)
```

Note that the above is a very *simple* parser based on the options you currently use. If more StackExchange.Redis configuration features need to be supported, you'll have to write more code to map those to equivalent Python Redis features (if available).

For *supported* connection string URLs you can use the [`redis.from_url()` function](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#redis.from_url), or the [`Redis.from_url()` class method](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#redis.Redis.from_url)

> Returns an active Redis client generated from the given database URL.

Note the supported schemes:

> Three URL schemes are supported:
>
> - `redis:// <http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/redis>`_ creates a normal TCP socket connection
> - `rediss:// <http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/rediss>`_ creates a SSL wrapped TCP socket connection
> - `unix://` creates a Unix Domain Socket connection

Note that `StrictRedis` is just an alias for the `redis.client.Redis` class.